# How send bytes32 in web3.py?

Tags: web3js, python

Constructor takes byte32 value. How send32 value, using web3.py or only python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In web3.py v4+, you can send either a hex string, or native Python `bytes`, like:

```
contract.constructor('0xf005ba11').transact()
contract.constructor(b'\xf0\x05\xba\x11').transact()
```

Comment: It doesn't work because I get "Could not identify the intended function with name"

Comment: @aabdulwahed I'm guessing that you're using `ConciseContract`. Try it again without `ConciseContract`. If that doesn't solve your problem, please start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

How to convert/encode string to bytes32 in Python for Solidity bytes32 arguments via web3.py

```
zBytes = "YAY!! Less than 32"
#zBytes = "YAY!! We Are Going To Make Ethereum & Python Great! Go Crypto and Blockchain and DAG, etc...!!!"
len1 = len(zBytes)
if len1 > 32:
    print('input string length: '+ str(len1)+ ' is too long')
    zBytes32 = zBytes[:32]
else:
    print('input string length: '+ str(len1)+ ' is too short')
    print('More characters needed: '+ str(32-len1))
    zBytes32 = zBytes.ljust(32, '0')
print('zBytes32 = '+ str(zBytes32)+ ' and its length: '+ str(len(zBytes32)))
xBytes32 = bytes(zBytes32, 'utf-8')
print('xBytes32 = '+ str(xBytes32))
contractInstance.functions.yourFunctionName(xBytes32).buildTransaction()
```